# adding data points to a box plot

Tags: r, boxplot

Wondering if anybody can help up. 
We've created a box plot we're happy with showing the shannon index of different communities.

The code we've used so far is:

```
wood <- c(1.2424533,1.3321779,1.0549202,2.0253262,0.7963116)
grass <- c(0.9743148,1.0397208,0.6931472,0,0.6365142)
scrub <- c(0,0.6365142,0.6931472,1.0397208,1.0986123,1.760146,
          1.4648164,0.6365142,1.2148897)

t.test(wood, grass, var.equal=T) ##t = -0.79206, df = 10, p-value = 0.4467 

t.test(wood, scrub, var.equal=T)

t.test(scrub, grass, var.equal=T)

lab <- c("Woodland","Grassland","Scrub")

boxplot(wood, grass, scrub, xlab="Treatment", ylab="Shannon Index", 
  col=c("darkolivegreen2", "darkolivegreen3", "darkolivegreen4")) 

posn <- c(1,2,3)
axis(side=1, at = posn, labels = lab)
```

and now we want the points on top of each individual box plot in the same graph?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something like what you envisioned?
The actual data-points are plotted on top of the box-plot.

```
wood <- c(1.2424533, 1.3321779, 1.0549202, 2.0253262, 0.7963116)
grass <- c(0.9743148, 1.0397208, 0.6931472, 0, 0.6365142)
scrub <- c(0, 0.6365142, 0.6931472, 1.0397208, 1.0986123, 1.760146, 
          1.4648164, 0.6365142, 1.2148897)

gr <- list(Woodland=wood, Grassland=grass, Scrub=scrub)

bp <- boxplot(gr, xlab="Treatment", ylab="Shannon Index", outcex=0,
  col=c("darkolivegreen2", "darkolivegreen3", "darkolivegreen4")) 

points(stack(gr)[,2:1], pch=21, bg="grey")
```

[image: Boxplot with data points overlaid]